# Class return INT but variable complains

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple class with a method that return the number of the current week. When I try to set the INT value from the method to the INT variable weekNum in the Controller, I get a red line below the call to the class method and an error message with something about "Cannot implicitly convert type....to int". Why? Both are INT, are they not!? The return type is INT for the method. Have I missed something here? I guess it's just a minor error I have done?

Inside the Controller:

```
int weekNum = new Namespace.Helpers.Week();
```

My class with method:

```
public class Week
{
    public int WeekNum()
    {
        var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("se-SE");
        var dateTimeInfo = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(culture);
        var dateTime = DateTime.Today;
        int weekNumber = culture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dateTime, dateTimeInfo.CalendarWeekRule, dateTimeInfo.FirstDayOfWeek);

        return weekNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not calling the method - you're just calling the constructor. Look at your calling code - you don't mention `WeekNum` anywhere.

Comment: int weekNum = new Namespace.Helpers.Week().WeekNum();

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: No, the code is creating an instance but not calling a method.

Comment: I got it! I should have seen that myself, but I'm tired and I have been sitting  in front of the computer to many hours! Please stop downvoting! Whats the point!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class does not return the value, the method does:

```
var week = new Namespace.Helpers.Week();

int weekNum = week.WeekNum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign Week class instance to int variable.

You should do something like this:

```
Week week = new Week();
int weekNum = week.WeekNum();
```

Or change your Week class to static.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your scenario by implement [implicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) to int in your class. Just change `WeekNum()` to `implicit operator`:

```
public class Week
{
    public static implicit operator int(Week d)
    {
        var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("se-SE");
        var dateTimeInfo = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(culture);
        var dateTime = DateTime.Today;
        int weekNumber = culture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dateTime, dateTimeInfo.CalendarWeekRule, dateTimeInfo.FirstDayOfWeek);

        return weekNumber;
    }
}
```

Note that it is not best practice and the better way is to use one of the other answers that recommends to use instance method.